# RangeError using Adobe PDF Embed API on Google Chrome or Edge

Tags: javascript

When trying to open bigger PDF documents, over 500 pages or 8MB the viewer loads only the first 2-3 pages (if we keep refreshing randomly it displays 2-3 pages correctly) and all other pages are shown blank.

We receive the following error in the console: "Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at C (acrobatProxy.js:1:92208)"

This happens only in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge so far. In Firefox it displays all pages correctly of the same PDF.

Are there any solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps people with the same issue.

After investigating we were able to replicate the issue and the solution is simple:

- in Google Chrome or Edge press CTRL + Shift + Del and Clear cache "Cached images and files"

The above seems to be a rendering issue, the document is incomplete so the browser gets into an infinite loop and timeouts.

By clearning cache on the client side the document is re-downloaded and all is working.